# Misc. process changing date format

Tags: windows, asp-classic, vbscript, registry

I have a page displayed in classic ASP. 90% of the time the dates on the page show on users' machines as MM/DD/YY - same as the international settings in the registry for short date format.  About 10% of the time this gets switched around and is presented as DD/MM/YY.  After a restart of the machine MM/DD/YY is displayed again.

I assume some process has run which is changing the default date format.  Any ideas on what I can do to a.) diagnose which program may be changing the date format and b.) how to ensure the default format is in place before loading my page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Version of IIS?  Does the site have intergrated security enabled?

Comment: It's not for your page to worry about.  Your page simply tells the browser to display the date, the local system is responsible for deciding how.  That why the system allows users to customize these settings in the first place.  From an ASP perspective, it shouldn't make any difference at all.  You're trying to code around behavior that is designed to be there.

Comment: @Nilpo: I think you are a little confused. To what are you refering when you say "local system"?  The client PC where the browser is?  The browser will receive HTML the content of which may be a date that has been formatted already by the browser.  The "local system" has little choice but to display the HTML as provided by the server.

Comment: You made it sound like client-side code.  Are you saying that the time format is changing on the server?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the complicated way that IIS and Windows are trying to figure out the "default" way to specify the date since you haven't explicitly set it in the code.

You can read more here on MSFT about the [date format randomly changing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306044).

You said a reboot fixes it, which to me implies someone is logging on to the machine and that person has a different date format. The reboot kicks them off, and it reverts back.

The workaround is just to set your date format explicitly in the code, but that's a different question.